# Prevent IIS Url Rewrite module from modifying HTTP 303/307 responses

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have the follow rewrite rule defined in IIS that I would like to maintain.  The problem I am encountering is that when the application behind this rewrite returns an HTTP redirect response (303 or 307) to a host other than itself, the URL rewrite module is changing the host on the `Location` header of the response.  (I have confirmed that the URL Rewrite is at fault since this behavior is not observed when accessing the site directly).  IIS is doing this even though I do **not** have any outbound rules defined.  How do I keep IIS rewriting the incoming requests, but prevent it from doing this unconfigured and unintended processing of the outgoing responses?

```
<rule name="ServiceName Rewrite">
  <match url="^(ServiceName/)?(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^ServiceName([.]company[.]com)?$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://generic.company.com/ServiceName/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

**Edit:**

To clarify, my web application is returning a response of

```
HTTP 307
Location: http://somesite.company.com/path/to/item
```

and IIS is unhelpfully changing this to

```
HTTP 307
Location: http://ServiceName.company.com/path/to/item
```

Comment: IIS seems to be working correctly since the client needs to receive the redirection response with the location of the "other" host. How else would the client know where to be redirected to unless the redirection response provides this location in response to the initial request?

Comment: I edited the question to better clarify what is happening.  My web application is returning a properly formed HTTP redirect that works both in development and when the site is accessed from an address that doesn't go through the URL rewrite module.  However, the URL Rewrite module is modifying the output such that the redirect no longer works.

Comment: Is the question mark character ( '?' ) needed in the match tag? That may cause IIS to always apply the rewrite action. What happens if you remove that character?

Comment: I do want the rule to invoke in all cases where the condition (listed in the conditions block) is true.  In other words, the condition block is what is restricting the rule, not the match.  For a previous version of the site (prior to the redirection issue), the match was intentionally set to `^(.*)` to match everything.  The match was changed so that I could exclude certain characters from the group when I was using the match data with the replacement group (notice the `{R:2}` in the action URL).

Comment: Doesn't the ? character in RegEx mean 0 or 1 for the prior expression? 0 means its OK if the prior expression was not matched and is therefore not required.

Comment: You are correct.  In other words, I want to match in call cases allowed by the conditions.  However, if that string is there, I don't want it in the group I use for replacement in the action.  Overall, the problem is not that the rule is getting invoked.  I want the module to process incoming requests.  What I don't want to happen is for the module to modify the outbound responses.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with my redirects.

What worked for me was:

1. In IIS Manager go to your server
2. Enter **Application Request Routing Cache**
3. In Actions go to **Server Proxy Settings**
4. Disable checkbox "***Reverse rewrite host in response headers***"
5. Restart your server

Comment: This was a life saver for me.. tried so many things.. but it was as simple as you mentioned here..

Comment: Thankyou my boss this is a time saver